# Setting scroll height of div on mount causing error React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have the following **div/container** which simply contains multiple `<p/>` tags. The container has a `ref` called `divRef` which is defined at the top of the code using `useRef` and is initialized to `null`

```
      <div ref={divRef} style={styles.messageListContainer}>
            <p>Placeholder</p>
            // multiple more <p/> tags here
      </div>
```

Here is the CSS for the container:

```
messageListContainer: {
    height: '100vh`,
    width: '100%',
    paddingBottom: 20,
    flexDirection: "column",
    display: "flex",
    overflow: "auto",
},
```

On mount, I want to the div to automatically be at the bottom end, and then users are able to **scroll up** in order to see previous content. I don't want to use `scrollIntoView` as I don't want the user to see the scrolling animation, I want the div to automatically be at the bottom end.

I try to accomplish this using the following `useEffect`, however I get the error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollHeight')`. Why does this error occur, and how can I accomplish my desired behaviour?

**useEffect to set the scroll at the bottom of the div:**

```
   useEffect(() => {
        divRef.current.scrollTop = divRef.current.scrollHeight
    }, [])
```

Comment: This is tricky to implement. See https://github.com/vytenisu/use-chat-scroll

Answer (score 0):

This is because `useEffect` runs before the component has finished (or even started) rendering. If the div doesn't exist, then it doesn't have a height. You need to confirm the existence of the divRef before trying to use it.

Add `divRef` to the dependency array and check that `divRef.current` exists.

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (divRef.current) {
      divRef.current.scrollTop = divRef.current.scrollHeight;
   }
}, [divRef])
```

Also, the `element.scrollIntoView()` method [has options you can pass](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) to make the scrolling instant:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   if (divRef.current) {
      divRef.current.scrollIntoView({
         behavior: 'instant',
         block: 'end'
      })
   }
}, [divRef])
```